# For a commutative exact sequence show that $V_1$ and $V_3$ are finite dimensional iff $V_2$ and $V_4$ also are.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence

For the following commutative exact sequence:
\begin{array}\\
 &V_1 & \stackrel{A_1}{\longrightarrow}  & V_2\\
 & \uparrow_{A_4} &&\downarrow _{A_2}\\
 &V_4 & \stackrel{A_3}{\longleftarrow} & V_3
\end{array}
Let $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$, $V_4$ be vector spaces and $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $A_4$ be homomorphism. Show that $V_1$ and $V_3$ are finite dimensional if and only if $V_2$ and $V_4$ also are.

---

As the diagram is exact and commutative, it can be said hat:
\begin{array}\\
\ker(A_1) = \operatorname{Im}(A_4) & \ker(A_2) = \operatorname{Im}(A_1) \\
\ker(A_3) = \operatorname{Im}(A_2) & \ker(A_4) = \operatorname{Im}(A_3)
\end{array}
Also, if $V_1$ and $V_3$ are finite-dimensional, then:
\begin{array}\\
\dim(V_1)&=\dim(\ker(A_1))+ \dim(\operatorname{Im}(A_1))\\
\dim(V_3)&=\dim(\ker(A_3))+ \dim(\operatorname{Im}(A_3))
\end{array}

I don't know what should I do next. I would really appreciate your answers.

Comment: With the convention that $\infty+n=\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb N\cup\{\infty\}$, rank-nullity also holds for infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something.  Wouldn't the commutativity of that diagram mean $A_4\circ A_3\circ A_2\circ A_1$ is the identity map?  If so, each $A_i$ is an isomorphism, so it becomes trivial... Is the diagram correct?  If so, what else would the commutativity of a cycle mean?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, $A_4\circ A_3\circ A_2\circ A_1$ is the identity map and the diagram is correct. But why should $A_i$ be an isomorphism?

Comment: If that were the case, we'd similarly have $$A_4A_3A_2A_1 = \text{id}_{V_1} \\ A_1A_4A_3A_2 = \text{id}_{V_2} \\ A_2A_1A_4A_3 = \text{id}_{V_3} \\ A_3A_2A_1A_4 = \text{id}_{V_4}$$ so in particular $A_4^{-1} = A_3A_2A_1$ by the first and last lines (and similarly for every other $A_i$).  However, then the only way we'd have exactness is if $V_1 \simeq V_2 \simeq V_3 \simeq V_4 \simeq 0$.  This is why I think my understanding of that commutative diagram must be wrong, because the whole question collapses into triviality.  @Bernard Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

The short exact sequence $\;0\longrightarrow \ker A_2\longrightarrow V_2\longrightarrow \operatorname{Im}A_2\longrightarrow 0$ is split since we have vector spaces. Now $\ker A_2\simeq \operatorname{Im}A_1$, which is finite dimensional, and similarly $ \operatorname{Im}A_2\simeq\ker A_3$, which is also finite dimensional.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I understand that $V_2 \stackrel{A_2}{\longrightarrow} \operatorname{Im}A_2 \stackrel{A_3}{\longrightarrow}  0$ with $A_2$ being surjective (any homomorphism is surjective to its own image) and $A_3(Im (A_2))=A_3(\ker(A_3))=0$. How is  $0\longrightarrow \ker A_2\longrightarrow V_2$ explained? On the other hand, I understand that $V_2/\ker(A_2) \cong Im A_2$, but why is $\ker A_2 \cong Im A_1$

Comment: You wrote they're actually  equal yourself!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know equality implied isomorphism. Could you please explain me why does $0\longrightarrow \ker A_2\longrightarrow V_2$ make sense? I still don't know how to continue, I am having trouble in trying to understand this.

Comment: $\ker A_2$ is a subspace of $V_2$, so we consider the canonical injection, that's all. Feel free to ask for any unclear point.

Comment: Thanks, the short exact sequence is now clear; however, I still don't understand how could I use it here. Could you give me an additional hint please?

Comment: For instance, the short exact sequence I considered in my answer is split. This means $V_2\simeq \ker A_2\otimes \operatorname{Im}A_2$, and the direct sum of finite dimensional vector spaces is finite dimensional, isn't it clear?

Comment: Thanks! I got the point. I did not understand the meaning of a short exact sequence (particularly the fact that $V_2\simeq \ker A_2\otimes \operatorname{Im}A_2$). I will still have to read a little bit more as I don't know the proof of this fact. Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean $V_2\cong\ker A_2\oplus\operatorname{im}A_2$.

Comment: just a small point : in my last comment, I mistyped (and forgot to check the result): I of course meant $\ker A_\oplus\operatorname{Im}A_2$. B.t.w. the result that the sequence is split means the middle rterm is isomorphic to the direct sum is more generally valid for modules over a commutative tring $R$ if the rightmost module is a free $R$-module.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos: Yes, I've just noticed the typo, but it's too late to edit the comment. Thank you for pointing it (and a happy new year)!